# Why am I getting default Spring profile when using sbt-assembly and passing the profile?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I have a simple Scala project I compile with sbt-assembly. When I get the jar and try to run like this

```bash
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=private target/scala-3.2.2/CalBackend-assembly-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I get

> INFO: No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"

I have tried other itterations...

```bash
java -jar target/scala-3.2.2/CalBackend-assembly-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.profiles.active=private                                 
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=private java -jar target/scala-3.2.2/CalBackend-assembly-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

But I always get the same. What am I missing?

When building with SBT this works fine

```bash
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=private sbt \~run
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Spring profiles but I guess they are defined in a properties file? Have you checked the file is indeed in the assembly jar?